# Get-credential results in "system cannot find the file specified"

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to write a powershell script that prompts for credentials and opens a webpage as the user.  I have

```
start-process -credential (get-credential) -filepath "http://www.microsoft.com"
```

It prompts for credentials, but then it outputs "This command cannot be run due to the error: The system cannot find the file specified."

I've tested it without the get-credential piece and it works fine.  What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

start-process -credential(get-credential) -filepath "C:\Program Files\Internet Explorer\iexplore.exe" -argumentlist "http://www.microsoft.com"

did the trick

Answer (score -1):

It seems to get confused due to switching credentials during the command -- or something. :)

Try this instead:

`start-process -credential (get-credential) -FilePath "powershell" -ArgumentList "start-process http://www.microsoft.com"`

This causes it to start a new Powershell instance under the new credentials, and then use that new instance to launch the web page.

Comment: Receiving the same error, just in a new window =(

Comment: What's the exact command line you tried?  The one I posted works fine here (Windows 7 64-bit, PowerShell v2).

Comment: I'm trying the exact command line you posted.  I can't actually see the error since it opens in a new window and closes, but it looks to be the same.